# Два маршрутизатора в одной подсети

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, подсети, cisco-packet-tracer, шлюз

Есть топология сети (представлена на скриншоте).
Как в подсети, в которой находятся два маршрутизатора, подключённые через свич, настроить шлюзы на компьютерах. Программа Cisco Packet Tracer[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

тут задача не полная, нужно было хотя бы примерные IP адреса указать

тут все можно решить с помощью static routing

ПК4 - 192.168.4.1
на маршрутизатор2 нужно прописать 192.168.4.0/24 на gate 192.168.3.1 (это маршрутизатор0)

на маршрутизаторе0 нужно добавить 2 роута
192.168.4.0/24 на gate 192.168.2.1
192.168.3.0/24 на gate 192.168.2.1

тут 192.168.3.0 это сеть компов ПК0, ПК1, ПК2, принтер

Если главный роутер маршрутизатор1

---

Если DefaultGateway это маршрутизатор0

тогда на в маршрутизаторах 2 и 1 нужно прописать по 2 роута что бы сетки 192.168.4.0 и 192.168.3.0 проходили через 0, а на 0 указывается 2 роута по порту, другие на default